# How to change dymola licence with python?

Tags: python, modelica, dymola

I'm working with different licenses of Dymola and I'm looking for a way to automatically change the license through Python. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change the license"? How would you do it without Python?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to modify

```
"...\AppData\Roaming\DassaultSystemes\Dymola\dymola.LIC"
```

to change the license that is used. As you mention you have different licenses you should have multiple license files already...

Likely it is a good option to have two license files and rename them. Dymola will by default look for the above file. So e.g. having one `dymola.lic` and another one `dymola_unused.lic` and replacing them with each other should solve the issue...

Comment: Thanks Markus, acually I use different server license (with server names and ports) and I want to swicht them with python scripst as I want to use.

Comment: For a network license, the license file contains address and port of the used server. So the above solution should work for as well for switching the server...

Comment: Or your switching tool could regenerate the appropriate three-line license file.